# Need to combine all element values

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I want to combine the  tag element values into single value

Xml I'm having:

```
<h1>aaa</h1>
<h1>bbb</h1>
<h1>ccc</h1>
```

XSL I used:

```
   <xsl:template match="h1[h1]">
      <h1><xsl:value-of select="h1"/></h1>
   </xsl:template>
```

But I'm currently getting like

```
<h1>aaa</h1>
<h1>bbb</h1>
<h1>ccc</h1>
```

But i need to be like:

```
<h1>aaa bbb ccc</h1>
```

Please suggest some code. Thanks in advance

Comment: If you want to group adjacent `h1` elements in XSLT 2.0 then see the example on using `for-each-group group-adjacent` in https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#grouping-examples.

Comment: You question is not clear, esp. the context. Please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code: `<h1><xsl:value-of select="h1"/></h1>` is OK, but you wrote it
in a wrong place.

You should use it in a template matching the **parent** tag (containg `h1`
tags) and add an empty template for `h1`, to prevent rendition of original
`h1` elements by the identity template.

Look at the following script:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="main">
    <xsl:copy>
      <h1><xsl:value-of select="h1"/></h1>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="h1"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

For the input given below:

```
<main>
  <h1>aaa</h1>
  <h1>bbb</h1>
  <h1>ccc</h1>
  <h2>xxx</h2>
</main>
```

It prints:

```
<main>
   <h1>aaa bbb ccc</h1>
   <h2>xxx</h2>
</main>
```